# Update ref parameter inside anonymous method

Tags: c#, ref, anonymous-methods

Is there a workaround to update a ref parameter inside an anonymous method?

I know that the an anonymous method doesn't allow access to ref parameters of the outer scope, but is there another way to do it? I am using an external library for the MessageStream so cannot alter the arguments of the delegate...

```
void DoWork(ref int count)
{
    MessageStream Stream = new MessageStream();
    Stream.MessageReceived += (o, args) =>
    {
        //Error cannot use ref or out parameter inside anonymous method
        count++;
    };
}
```

Comment: The answer depends on whether you can be sure the `Stream.MessageReceived` will be raised before `DoWork` returns. Can you be sure of that?

Comment: do you know unsafe context? If no I post an answer with this solution

Comment: @faby I think I know what you're thinking of, and if I'm right, that won't work. It will *usually* work, but it will sometimes fail, and there is no way to fix it so that it always works.

Comment: Why do you have `ref` on that parameter? Are you sure you need it? It's very rare to see it being used. If you can show us more about how this is used, we might be able to suggest another way that'll work right.

Comment: @hvd I kmow yes this is the problem with unasafe context

Comment: @faby Unsafe code is not inherently broken. There is plenty of correct and useful unsafe code. But you have to make sure you are aware of what the language and runtime guarantee, and what they don't. If you're not, you won't get a nice warning telling you what you're doing wrong, it can fail in the most spectacular ways imaginable.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to go down the unsafe context road. It sounds like it will cause me more problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case there is no viable work-around to this problem: by the time the `Stream.MessageReceived` event fires, the `count` may be well out of scope in the caller of your `DoWork` function.

In situations like that you should encapsulate the `count` in an object, and keep a reference to that object in both the event handler and in the caller, like this:

```
class Counter {
    public int Value {get;private set;}
    public void Increment() {Value++;}
}
void DoWork(Counter count) {
    MessageStream Stream = new MessageStream();
    Stream.MessageReceived += (o, args) => {
        count.Increment();
    };
}
```

Comment: Possibly Interlocked.Increment might be sensible here, depending on usage.

Comment: I think this is the only way I can achieve it. A bit of code re-jigging in order. I was hoping it would all play nice somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the delegate update a variable from an outter scope, pass a lambda that sets the value instead of passing the count by `ref`.

```
//shared var
private static int _count = 0;

//call your method
DoWork(() => _count++);  //instead of DoWork(ref _count);


void DoWork(Action countInc)
{
    MessageStream Stream = new MessageStream();
    Stream.Activated += (o, args) => countInc();
}
```