# Run code only once using dispatcher

Tags: c#, dispatcher, ref

I have a simple pattern to run code only once. It's mostly used to Update something on the UI, while it may change very often in the Background.

```
private bool _updating;
private void UpdateSomething()
{
    if (!_updating)
    {
        _updating = true;

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                _updating = false;
                DoSomething();
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}
```

I would prefer to put the boilerplate code inside a simple method:

```
public static void RunOnce(Action action, ref bool guard)
{
    if (!guard)
    {
        guard = true;

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                guard = false;
                action();
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}
```

und call it like this:

```
void UpdateSomething()
{
    RunOnce(DoSomething, ref _updating);
}
```

However, this does not work as you cannot have ref parameters inside anonymous methods.
Is there any workaround, e.g. to pin the ref parameter and free it when the method was executed?

Comment: can you not declare bool guard as a private static like this 
`private static bool guard = false`; 
look at this posting as well for example of how to declare a ref param inside of an anonymous method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630765/update-ref-parameter-inside-anonymous-method

Comment: Making the guard static is not an option, as I update multiple instances individually. However, putting it into a reference type like in the linked thread would be an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void RunOnce(Action action, ref RunOnceToken token)
{
    if (token == null || token.IsCompleted)
    {
        token = new RunOnceToken(
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                action,
                DispatcherPriority.Background));
    }
}

public sealed class RunOnceToken : IDisposable
{
    private DispatcherOperation _operation;

    public RunOnceToken(DispatcherOperation operation)
    {
        if (operation != null &&
            operation.Status != DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed &&
            operation.Status != DispatcherOperationStatus.Aborted)
        {
            _operation = operation;
            _operation.Completed += OnCompletedOrAborted;
            _operation.Aborted += OnCompletedOrAborted;
        }
    }

    private void OnCompletedOrAborted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return _operation == null; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var operation = _operation;
        if (operation == null)
            return;

        _operation = null;

        operation.Completed -= OnCompletedOrAborted;
        operation.Aborted -= OnCompletedOrAborted;
    }
}
```

Your example usage would change to:

```
private RunOnceToken _updateToken;

private void UpdateSomething()
{
    RunOnce(DoSomething, ref _updateToken);
}
```

It doesn't really matter if you never clear your copy of the token, because the wrapped `DispatcherOperation` gets cleared out upon completion to avoid leaking `action` or any values it captures.

In case it wasn't obvious, none of this is concurrency-safe; I assume everything above is only accessed from the UI thread.

One useful enhancement might be to add an optional `DispatcherPriority` argument to `RunOnce` such that you can control the priority level used to schedule `action` (perhaps canceling an already-scheduled operation if it was scheduled at a lower priority).

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Indeed, this is used in UI Thread as I simply want to update many items in a collection (or in multiple objects), and when this operation is finished (the UI-Thread is idle again), the changes will be presented on the UI, e.g. using Linq.

Just for curiosity: What would be the worst that would happen if this would be called from another thread? I think, the Update method could run multiple times, but on a single thread. So as long as the processed data is thread-safe, nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Well, depending on what your update code actually does, there may be a hazard: if you call `RunOnce` when an update is already in progress, you don't know how far along that update is.  It's possible, then, that the update won't reflect your latest data, and since it hasn't completed, you won't schedule another.  You could redesign this to be more aggressive and clear its 'scheduled' state when the operation *starts* instead of when it *completes* (or aborts).  Better to have extra updates than to miss one.  There are some unsynchronized reads and writes going on, but they look mostly benign.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice. Indeed, that was the reason why I reset the guard at the start of the dispatcher operation. Anyway, calling the method from another thread would defeat its purpose, as in this case the chance is large that the UI thread is idle and will handle the update too early...

Comment: Hey, I've posted an answer based on yours but I'm not completely sure if it's correct , could you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

I was no aware about `DispatcherOperation` existence, however seen Mike Strobel answer I wrote following code. I'm not 100% sure about it but it seems to work without to much boilerplate.

```
public static class DispatcherExtensions {
    public static int clearInterval = 10_000;

    private static long time => DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
    private static long lastClearTime = time;
    private static Dictionary<int, DispatcherOperation> currOperations = new Dictionary<int, DispatcherOperation>();
    private static object sync = new object();

    public static void invokeLastAsync(this Dispatcher d,  Action a, DispatcherPriority p = DispatcherPriority.Background, [CallerFilePath]object key1 = null, [CallerLineNumber]object key2 = null) {
        lock (sync) {
            DispatcherOperation dop;
            var k = key1.GetHashCode() ^ key2.GetHashCode();
            if (currOperations.ContainsKey(k)) {
                dop = currOperations[k];
                currOperations.Remove(k);
                dop.Abort();
            }
            dop = d.BeginInvoke(a, p);
            clearOperations(false);
            currOperations.Add(k, dop);
        }
    }

    public static void clearOperations(bool force = true) {
        var ct = time;
        if (!force && ct - lastClearTime < clearInterval) return;
        var nd = new Dictionary<int, DispatcherOperation>();
        foreach (var ao in currOperations) {
            var s = ao.Value.Status;
            if (s == DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed
                || s == DispatcherOperationStatus.Aborted)
            nd.Add(ao.Key, ao.Value);
        }
        currOperations = nd;
        lastClearTime = ct;
    }

}
```

Basically extension method take file path and line number as a key to store `DispacherOperation` instance in a dictionary, and If the key already have an operation, its aborted and replaced with new operation. Periodically, the dictionary is cleared, from completed/aborted actions that are no longer invoked.

The usage is very simple:

```
private int initCount = 0;
private int invokeCount = 0;
private void updateSomething() {
    initCount++;
    view.Dispatcher.invokeLastAsync(() => {
        Console.WriteLine($@"invoked {++invokeCount}/{initCount}");
    });
}
```

I haven't run to any issue with this so far. Maybe someone else could see some weak spot.